# Extracting an NSArray from a CKRecord in Swift with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, cloudkit, ckrecord

How can" I fill an NSArray (an array of strings) from a CKRecord?

I created the record successfully with: myPrivateDatabase.saveRecord

and I can fetch the record successfully with: myPrivateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID

I can see that the data is in the record with: println(returnRecord.objectForKey("key1")) in the form of comma delimited, quoted strings

But I can't figure out how to get that back into the NSArray

Help!

Thanks :-)

Comment: Please specify what statements you used to put the NSArray into that record. I suspect you just assigned the array to the string property and now you want to convert it back to an array, right?

Comment: Edwin, thanks for the reply!  In the interim I've started working on exactly your suggestion, right down to watching out for quotes in the text!  I was hoping I was overlooking a magic statement of some kind.  I used 'record.setObject' to put the array in, why isn't there a 'record.getObject' to get it out?! :-}

Comment: (continued) More precisely I used <<myRecord.setObject(arrayOfItems, forKey: "key1")>> and wanted there to be <<arrayOfItems = myRecord.getObjectForKey("key1")>> to get it back.  As far as parsing the record, I'm looking at inserting some unique special cahracts to mark the beginning and end of strings to avoid restrictions in the strings and swallow them when reading the strings back.  Thanks again.

Comment: For the record, that worked great (I used square brackets to delineate the items).

Answer (score 0):

If you just put the array in a string field, then you have to parse it back.

```
let line = returnRecord.objectForKey("key1")
let values = line.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(returnRecord.objectForKey("key1"))
```

then just loop through the values and remove the leading and trailing quotes. You do have to be aware that it will go wrong when you have strings that contains a comma. To solve that issue you should use NSScanner for parsing the line

Did you specify the field in CloudKit as a 'String List' or is it a String?